# PHP isnull First pass/Second pass flag

Tags: php, session, reload, isnull

I have a PHP results page which starts off "first-pass" with ALL rows returned. It's a search listing of all pizza places in the county.

```
SELECT * from pizzeria;
```

Then the user can drill down into more detail... the page also has a CSS dropdown menu where the user can pick a specific neighborhood (which carries a URL):

```
href="samepage.php?neighborhood=HELLSKITCHEN"
```

which then changes the query after I pick up the `$_GET[]`

```
SELECT * from pizzaria WHERE nbh=(the $_GET[] variable sent in the URL);
```

but I'd like the page to call itself and I have `header("Cache-Control:no-cache");` at the top.

I'm trying to create a first-pass or first visit flag variable with the `isnull()` function:

```
if (is_null($firstpass)) {
    $query = SELECT all the records from the pizzaria table
} else {
    $query = SELECT only the records WHERE I $_GET[] the value from the reloaded URL
}
```

It seems though that the `$firstpass` variable doesn't stick on reloads. Should I SESSION that variable? (though still have the problem of constantly resetting it)

Or maybe implement some other approach?

I know I can redirect to a separate second page and javascript back to this page to avoid "headers already sent", but I want to avoid the round-trip back to the client.

Is there a known best practice on reloads with new info? Kinda new to PHP here. thanks

Comment: You realize there is only one "a" in "pizzeria", right?

Comment: lol oops - wow wat a crummy italian I am

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I didn't understand well your problem but why wouldn't you do :

```
if (!isset($_GET['example'])) {
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM pizzerias';
} else {
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM pizzerias WHERE pizzeria = \'.mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['example']).\' LIMIT 1';
}
```

at the first pass because, it seem that the $_GET variable is set only when the user choose a pizzeria?

Comment: WARNING: This method is vulnerable to SQL injections DO NOT USE IT!

Comment: @user1349089 `pizzerias` needs to also be `pizzeria`, there SQL vulnerabilities, and it will only display ONE result, whereas you wanted an ENTIRE neighborhood's worth of results. I think xavier Z botched this answer. You should probably reconsider your decision as this being the "answer".

Comment: @GlennDayton thanks on the vulnerability topic. I'll search the board for SQL injection defenses. Again, I'm new to PHP but probably the injection topic has been discussed many times here. I'm sure I'll find a bunch of threads.

Comment: ok found a bunch of threads on mysql_real_escape_string(). thanks again.

Comment: @user1349089 My answer was very comprehensive, you may want to reconsider.

Comment: @glenn-dayton hi! many thanks to point out this issue, aswer edited.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more targeted answer.

**NOTICE:** `mysql_*` functions are being depreciated, so use PDO instead. In my example I'm being semi-lazy and not using PDO.

```
//Connect to database and define table up here
...
if(!isset($_GET['neighborhood')){
    $q = "SELECT * FROM pizzeria;";
}else{
    $q = sprintf("SELECT * FROM pizzeria WHERE nbh=%s",mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['neighborhood']));
}
$query = mysql_query($q);
foreach($row = mysql_fetch_array($query,MYSQL_ASSOC){
    //display the updated view of restaurants.
}
```

I would also suggest that you use [jQuery](http://jquery.com) for that Web 2.0 effect. It's really nice when you select from a drop-down menu and things magically move without a page reload.

Comment: don't you think you are out of the subject? no mysql_* function anywhere here!

Comment: He's using PHP. At least my method demonstrates knowledge of this particular subject.

Comment: ok there is a lazy factor here (tho its more timing). Not using PDO but I did add the mysql_real_escape_string() functions. got it. thanks